# What's the trivial difference between the 15" and 17" versions of the MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

What can I ask on the phone to a Mac user who has a MacBook Pro (Alu), but doesn't know if it's a 15 or a 17 one (and don't have a tool to measure the screen)

What can I ask him to look at to tell me what version it is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the left corner of the top menu, pick the apple menu and select `About This Mac`.

In the `About This Mac` panel, click the `More Info`  button. if you hover your mouse on `Hardware` you can see the general info about your macbook pro such 15" or 17".

[image]

As [Dori](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/351/dori) said in comment above solution for before 2007 now choose Graphics/Displays from the left column, it does display the screen resolution.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that there were information in the "top chapters" of that tree. Thanks !

Comment: Mine tells only "MacBook Pro" :-( (it's 13")

Comment: @peter As I test it in my macbook pro 13" it tells just MacBook Pro too,so I choose pic from google.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you look at the screenshot, it's from 2007—System Profiler no longer shows the dimensions. However, if you choose Graphics/Displays from the left column, it does display the screen resolution.

Answer (score 9):

If it's the unibody MacBook Pro, I believe the 15" has an **SD card slot**, and the 17" has an **ExpressCard/34 slot**. Also, the 15" only has **two USB ports**, whereas the 17" has **three**.

[image: 15" MacBook Pro]

[image: 17" MacBook Pro]

Comment: In earlier models it's a bit different - the late 2008 15" has an ExpressCard slot. Still only 2 USB sockets though.

Answer (score 4):

Might not be that Trivial, but *the size between* the side of the computer and the keyboard is larger in a 17’’ model:

MacBook Pro 15’’:

[15'' http://www.sunsetmac.com/images/6615244.gif](http://www.sunsetmac.com/images/6615244.gif)

MacBook Pro 17’’:

[image: 17'']

If the user fails to find the information as described above, you can tell him to count the number of holes (no measure required!) ;)

Comment: Yeah, a 15" MBP has 1645 holes in each speaker grille, a 17" has more. Or did by "holes" did you mean the ports on the sides? Counting those might be a bit easier.

Comment: Nono, I meant the “holes” in the speaker grille ;)

Answer (score 3):

Max screen resolution in Displays preferences.